# Mismatch between system's time and date.toLocaleTimeString

Tags: javascript

**UPDATE:** The issue existed on Android Chrome 58. Upgrading Chrome resolved it. I'd still like to know what was causing this issue.

I'm browsing this [link](http://www.localeplanet.com/support/browser.html) on my Android phone and it shows:

```
date: ... 00:55:23
date.toLocaleTimeString(): 11:55:23 PM
```

My locale is `de_DE` and correct time showing at the top of my phone is indeed `00:55`.

How is this possible? Isn't `00:55` just `12:55` ?

Comment: I suspect a timezone or daylight saving time issue, since it's off by 1 hour.

Comment: What time do you get here? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_tolocaletimestring

Comment: may be you have to use  some other identifier  http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html

Comment: @sunknudsen same as above, one hour earlier than system's.